# Resource Graphs in top panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-classic

I'm running Gnome Classic in Ubuntu 11.10 and in previous versions of Ubuntu it was fairly easy to get resource graphs to appear in the top menu, but now the regular way of getting said graphs in the top menu bar don't work (right clicking on the top menu produces no result unless you click on an icon, eg sound, wifi, or battery indicators). Is it not possible to get resource graphs in the top menu bar in Gnome Classic on Ubuntu 11.10? If not Gnome Classic, is it possible in KDE?

I've tried googling but the only results I'm getting are related to adding the panel, which I can't do because I can't right click on the top menu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You can add the system monitor applet to the gnome-panel as shown in the picture.

To add, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> and right-click the gnome-panel to add the system monitor applet.

*Note - this picture was taken using 12.04 Gnome-Classic*

Comment: Thank you, ALT + WIN was the bit I was missing, I don't recall having to do that before so the behavior must have changed (or I'm crazy) recently.

Comment: @fossfreedom Does the gnome fallback in 12.04 is good or 'cool'?

Comment: @Ravi - is it usable?  yes ... is it cool? - IMHO - I prefer cinnamon or unity.

Comment: @fossfreedom I think unity rocks..........

Comment: Thanks.  They hid that one so well, I would never have found it.